# EuiccManager switchToSubscription

Tags: android, euiccmanager

I am prototyping an eSIM install/subscription use case by following the following doc:  https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-overview:

I have successfully download the profile that I can subscribe to it if I use the device settings app.  However it fails silently if I try to subscribe to it using the following API:

```
mgr.switchToSubscription(1 /* subscriptionId */, callbackIntent);
```

Anyone has any pointer what is **subscriptionId**?  or any pointer how to look for more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscription ID the the ID used by [`SubscriptionManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager), which you can get from `SubscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId()` or the [`getSubscriptionIds()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#getSubscriptionIds(int)) method.

Unfortunately, the documentation for that class is quite sparse. But if you just need to know the subscription ID of your eSIM, you can use the adb command

```
adb shell dumpsys isub
```

which will show you all of the available subscriptions as well as the currently active ones.

Note also that [`downloadSubscription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/euicc/EuiccManager#downloadSubscription(android.telephony.euicc.DownloadableSubscription,%20boolean,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) has a `switchAfterDownload` method, so you don't need to get the subscription ID to switch to it manually, if you have the download operation immediately preceding it.